# Does contract logic get executed with a SimulatedBackend?

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-invocation, simulation

I am trying to write a test, but I am surprised by an unexpected behavior with the `SimulatedBackend`.

I am able to deploy the contract, and then call a function. The function runs an internal check, in `sol`:

```
    contract IDStore {
      mapping(uint256 => bytes) public ids;
    
      function add(uint256 id, bytes calldata key) external {
        require(ids[id].length == 0, "exists");
        ids[id] = key;
      }
```

I generated the contract bindings with `abigen`:
`abigen --abi ./store.json --pkg store --type IDStore --out ./idstore.abigen.go`

Now in the test I am trying to add the same id and key twice, expecting it to fail, but it doesn't.

```
    backend := backends.NewSimulatedBackend(
        core.GenesisAlloc{
            myaddr: core.GenesisAccount{
                Balance: big.NewInt(9900000000000000000),
            },
        }, 80000000)
    
    defer backend.Close()
    addr := deployTestContract(require)
    store, err := NewIDStore(addr, backend)
    req.NoError(err)
    // nonce 1
    auth := getAuth(1)
    id1 := big.NewInt(99)
    tx, err := store.Add(auth, id1, keybytes)
    backend.Commit()
    // expected
    req.NoError(err)

    // nonce 2
    auth = getAuth(2)
    tx, err = store.Add(auth, id1, keybytes)
    backend.Commit()
    // expected
    req.Error(err)
```

However the test always returns with `An error is expected but got nil.`

Am I not seeing something simple? Or does maybe contract storage work differently with SimulatedBackends somehow? Am I using it wrong? Does it not work at all with contract calls? Or is even the `sol` function bad? I am not responsible for the solidity part.

Answer (score 1):

Simulating a backend should be the main goal of SimulatedBackends so that I would say yes.

While I'm not an expert with the SimulatedBackends in geth code, I assume errors and failed transactions are treated normally as separate concepts. Hence, you must check the receipts to verify if a transaction failed.

It seems to me the code is testing if the sending of the transaction was successful, and so it was correct in both cases.

Now that the tx is correctly sent and the block is minted with `.Commit()`, you should check the receipt to get the result. There, you should be able to see the second transaction has failed.

Here, you can see a [full guide on using a simulated client](https://goethereumbook.org/en/client-simulated/). It's based on geth 1.8.10 (2018), but I don't think that part changed too much during the years.

In that guide, you can get the receipt and check the result with code like this:

```go
receipt, err := client.TransactionReceipt(context.Background(), signedTx.Hash())
if err != nil {
  log.Fatal(err)
}
if receipt == nil {
  log.Fatal("receipt is nil. Forgot to commit?")
}

fmt.Printf("status: %v\n", receipt.Status) // status: 1
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! Still, after the 2nd tx, my test fails at `require.Equal(uint64(0x0), receipt.Status)` - in other words I am expecting the Status to be a failure, but it returns 1, meaning the tx succeeded, which indeed is surprising.

Comment: Nit: changed the code to use directly `require.Equal(types.ReceiptStatusFailed, receipt.Status)`

Comment: Weird. Looking at the code the `backends.NewSimulatedBacked` is deprecated now, so maybe it's not a good choice anymore. They suggest using `simulated.Backend` from package `github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/ethclient/simulated` instead (https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/ethclient/simulated/backend.go)